# Is the kernel of a map to a finitely presented module finitely generated?

Tags: modules

Let $R$ be a ring (unital, not necessarily commutative), $M$ a finitely presented left $R$ module. Suppose $m_1,\ldots,m_n\in M$ generate $M$. This determines a surjection $f:R^n\to M$.

> Must the kernel of $f$ be finitely generated?

This is true by definition if the generating set $m_1,\ldots,m_n$ is the one coming from the finite presentation of $M$.

Comment: I just found [this identical question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1788/) on Mathoverflow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We'll prove it under bit more general setting. Let $0\to K\to R^m\to M\to 0$ be an exact sequence where $K$ is finitely generated. Consider now $0\to L\to R^n\to M\to 0$; we wish to prove that $L$ is finitely generated.

By [Schanuel's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel's_lemma), $L\oplus R^m\cong K\oplus R^n$. Then $L$ is an epimorphic image of $K\oplus R^m$, which is finitely generated.

By the way, this result is a corollary of following more general fact;

> If $0\to L\to N\to M\to 0$ is an exact sequence with $M$ a finitely presented and $N$ finitely
>   generated, then $L$ is finitely generated.

Indeed, consider an epimorphism $R^n\to N$ and the commutative diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> L' @>>> R^n @>>> M @>>> 0\\
@. @VVV @VVV @| \\
0 @>>> L @>>> N @>>> M @>>>0
\end{CD}
$$
where the arrow $R^n\to M$ is the composition of $N\to M$ after $R^n\to N$.

Then $L'$ is finitely generated by the above argument and the map $L'\to L$ is an epimorphism by diagram chasing (or [four lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma#Statements)).

This can also be proved by using Snake lemma instead of Schanuel's lemma (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1788/does-finitely-presented-mean-always-finitely-presented-answered-yes)).

Comment: How to define the map from $L^{'}$ to $L$ ? 

egreg

Comment: @user371231 If $f$ is the map from $R^n$ to $N$ and you assume, without loss of generality, that $L$ is a submodule of $N$, then $L'=f^{-1}(L)$ and the map is the restriction of $f$.

Comment: Is it true that an element $x \in L^{'}$ will go to $0$ in $N$  in this diagram ?

Comment: @user371231 Why should it? This is essentially the homomorphism theorem $(A/C)/(B/C)\cong A/B$.

Comment: So $L^{'}$ is not the kernel of the map $R^n \to N$

Comment: @user371231 No, as I said it's $f^{-1}(L)$

Comment: Oh i see , $L'$ is the kernel of the map $R^n \to M$

Comment: @user371231 Exactly. By the way, it's `$L'$`, not `$L^{'}$`: look at the difference between $L'$ and $L^{'}$.

Comment: Thank you for the correction sir