# For $0 \to N' \to N \to M \to 0 $ with $N$ finitely generated and $M$ finitely presented then $N^{'}$ is also finitely generated.

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module

Let $M$ be a finitely presented $R$ module and $0 \to N' \to N \to M \to 0 $ be an exact sequence with $N$ a finitely generated $R$ module. Prove that $N'$ is also a finitely generated $R$ module.

By $M$ finitely presented $R$ module we mean there is a ses $0 \to K \to F \to M \to 0$ where $F$ is free of finite rank and $K$ is finitely generated $R$ module. I proved the case when $N$ is free of finite rank but can't show it in this case. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_lemma

Comment: But can't apply Schanuel's lemma directly since don't know if $N$ is projective or not.

Comment: By assumption there is an epimorphism $F\to N$ where $F$ is a free module of finite rank. Consider the exact sequence  $$0\to N'\times_{N} F\to F\to M\to 0$$  Now Schanuel's lemma shows the module $ N'\times_{N} F$ is finitely generated. The result follows from that $ N'\times_{N} F\to N'$ is epic.

Comment: What is the module $N^{'}X_{N} F$ and what is the map to $F$?

Comment: $N'\times_N F$ is the pullback of the diagram $N'\to N\leftarrow F$. More precisely, it is the submodule of $N'\oplus F$ consisting of the elements $(x,y)\in N'\oplus F$ such that $x$ and $y$ map to the same element in $N$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1201068/62967

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F'$ be free of finite rank and $F' → N$ be surjective. You get an exact sequence
$$0 → K' → F' → M → 0,$$
for some kernel $K'$, where the right arrow is $F' → N → M$.  Apply [Schanuel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel's_lemma) to this sequence to get that $K'$ is finitely generated.

The arrow $K' → F' → N$ factorises via $N' → N$. So you get an arrow of exact sequences

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> K' @>>> F' @>>> M @>>> 0 \\
@| @VVV @VVV @| @| \\
0 @>>> N' @>>> N @>>> M @>>> 0 \\
\end{CD},
$$
upon which you can apply a [four lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma#Statements).